# Pycharm "Virtualenv Environment -> New Environment"

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv

In the PyCharm you can run `Virtualenv Environment -> New Environment`

What exactly does this command do? It creates new `venv` or `virtualenv`? And what is better to use for the project (Django)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyCharm you create a project-specific isolated virtual environment and its purpose is to manage settings and dependencies of a particular project regardless of other Python projects.

According to its website, Python 3.3+ versions use the 'venv' tool, instead of the third-party 'virtualenv.

I would use virtual environment for any python project, because you can keep your dependencies seperate and contains everything needed for your project to execute successfully.

Answer (score 1):

For my money, you're better of using Conda. The main reason being that Pip and Venv are Python specific package and environment management tools. Whereas Conda also looks after non-Python dependencies. Which can be very important for certain libraries.